# Get CURRENT_USER in MySQL trigger returns incorrect value

Tags: mysql, database

I have an old application ( no source code available ) that connects to a productive MySQL database. Due to business reasons we have to limit the access to the database. For this reason I have written a MySQL Trigger that will limit the users who have access to the database based on a ID.

The users authenticate against the database through the application with their own ID and their private passwords.

The problem appears inside the trigger were I have a `SELECT...WHERE` clause and the `WHERE` clause equals to: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(), @, 1)`

Basically each time a hit is done on a certain database / table by the user in the application I would like to capture that User ( which is also shows up in the Processes of MySQL server ) and based on the capture execute a `SELECT` statement which will return a UNIQUE ID for that given user. Based on that ID a `IF` check will be executed and access for saving data will be granted or revoked.

The problem is, even if I log in the application with User X the `CURRENT_USER()` function of MySQL somehow captures my domain user no matter what I do. It should capture the domain user that executes that trigger.

Full trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER dbname.disable_order_insert_trigger;

DELIMITER $
use dbname$

CREATE TRIGGER disable_order_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON 
dbname.dbtable

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE compCode INT unsigned DEFAULT 0;        
    SET @compCode = 1;

    SELECT COMPCODE
    INTO @compCode
    FROM dbname.user_info_table
    WHERE dbname.user_info_table.USERID = SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(), "@", 1) 
    AND dbname.user_info_table.COMPCODE = 1172 LIMIT 1; 
    SELECT CURRENT_USER() INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\temp\\compCode.txt';

IF @compCode = 1172 THEN 
    CALL something;
END IF;

END;
$
DELIMITER ; 

SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

My colleague logged into the MySQL Database through the application using he's PC / username and still in the `OUTFILE` my username gets written. Shouldn't `CURRENT_USER()` capture his username ?

The version of MySQL Database is: `5.1.19-beta-community-nt-debug`.
I have also tried to leave the `Definer` trigger property empty, still only my username gets captured and written to the file.

Comment: What kind of application programming language and DBMS access package do you use? (php/mysqli, java/connector.j, c#/connector.net, for example).  What is the connection string or credentials used by your *application*, not your *application's user,* to access the your database?

Comment: @O.Jones, it is a VB6 Legacy Application with some very old native connectors probably. We have no source code available.

Comment: Try: [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user) function.

Comment: Worth reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-activity-auditing.html

Comment: Your old application seems to be connecting to the database with the user returned by the [USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_user) function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like [wchiquto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316440/wchiquito) suggested in the comments, use `USER()` rather than `CURRENT_USER()`.

In a stored procedure, `CURRENT_USER()` presents the name of the stored procedure's definer.

Comment: tried with USER(), same problem. @Balazs Vago, as the document states those specific contexts ( Triggers, Stored Routines, Events  etc ) are returning the `DEFINER` and not the actual invoker of the Trigger, Routine, Events etc.

Comment: Thank you @O.Jones, @wchiquito and Balazs Vago for the documentation. After tweaking the trigger, it seems that it works. The `USER()` function returns the caller of the trigger and not the definer.

Comment: @darksleep how did you tweak the trigger to get it to work?

Comment: @johnchase, tweak in what sense ? It's been a few years

Comment: "After tweaking the trigger, it seems that it works"

I was wondering what tweak you made to return the current user, rather than then the creator of the trigger, which is what I get regardless of whether I use `CURRENT_USER` or `USER`. Although I think I may have figured it out,`SESSION_USER` seems to return the "active" user